# Using local files inside docker container

Tags: docker

I am writing a `dockerfile` for my `go` application. Here, I need a file which is located in `/home/saivamsi/.kube/config` on my local machine. If I am directly using it in the code, it is showing an error that no file or directory is found. So, i started using volumes for that but I don't know where it went wrong , I am unable to use that file in my code.

```
FROM golang:1.14.0

ENV HOMEABC=/home/saivamsi

WORKDIR  /go/src/bifrost

VOLUME  src="${HOMEABC}/.kube/config",target="/go/src/bifrost/config"

COPY --chown=bbadmin:bbadmin . /go/src/bifrost

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

RUN go build -o main .

#EXPOSE 8001

CMD ["./main"]
# CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of the `VOLUME` instruction in your Dockerfile is incorrect. The [Dockerfile reference for VOLUME](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes) states:

> **The host directory is declared at container run-time:** The host directory (the mountpoint) is, by its nature, host-dependent. This is to preserve image portability, since a given host directory can’t be guaranteed to be available on all hosts. For this reason, you can’t mount a host directory from within the Dockerfile. The VOLUME instruction does not support specifying a host-dir parameter. **You must specify the mountpoint when you create or run the container.**

To mount your `$HOME/.kube` directory on the host to the container at runtime, you would specify `--volume` or `-v` in your `docker run` command.

For example, you would first remove the `VOLUME` instruction from your Dockerfile. Then, you would run something like the following:

```
docker run --volume $HOME/.kube:/go/src/bifrost <image name>
```

This will mount your `$HOME/.kube` directory on your host to the `/go/src/bifrost` directory within the running container. The config file would then be present at `/go/src/bifrost/config` at runtime.

**NOTE:** This solution only works while the kube config file is present on the host on which you are running your container. To include the configuration file in the image itself, *it must* exist in the Docker build context.